# centering preloader in materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

Given this :

I want to use this Preloader with `position:fixed` and centered.So what i did was:

```css
.loader {
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
<body>
  <div class="preloader-wrapper big active loader">
    <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
      <div class="circle-clipper left">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="gap-patch">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

which causes an animation :-/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as your container has a declared width and height this will center the element horizontally and vertically. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqjy7jbb/7/)

```
.loader {
position: absolute;
top :0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Where this answer is _technically_ correct you should add a description as to what you changed and why it works. As it stands, this answer only services this specific situation and doesn't help future users.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly changed the loader's style which helps to remove the issue of showing scrollbar intermittently

```
<div className="preloader-wrapper big active loader">
    // spinners
</div>

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50vh;
  bottom: 50vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

index.html

```
<div class="loader">
      <div class="preloader-wrapper small active">
        <div class="spinner-layer spinner-green-only">
          <div class="circle-clipper left">
            <div class="circle"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="gap-patch">
            <div class="circle"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="circle-clipper right">
            <div class="circle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
```